# A word meaning a big show with a lot of noise but really nothing is changing

Tags: single-word-requests

Seeking a word describing a "big show," with a lot of noise, buzz, discussion, meetings, etc. but nothing is really changing.

Example:

"The congressional delegates have scheduled a series of meetings with their constituency representatives. The police, fire, ambulance crews and nurses will be in attendance. There will be round-table discussions, a march, and an open forum discussion."

...but nothing is changing.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is *razzmatazz*.

> **Razzmatazz:** a noisy and exciting activity meant to attract attention. It has overtones of mere show - with nothing achieved.

[[Merriam Webster English Language Learners Dictionary]](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/razzmatazz)

Comment: I am grateful for Decapitated Soul's edits today. I now think better of "Sleepy Hollow".  Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

How about a "Publicity Stunt"? It's an event that attracts attention, causes a lot of discussion but is actually shallow and not progressive.